# Chain grep commands to search for a pattern inside files that match another pattern

Tags: bash, grep

How can I chain multiple grep commands?

For example, if I want to search recursively for all PHP files that are publicly accessible, i.e those which contain `$_user_location   = 'public`; and search for `"SendQueue()` inside all these files, what should I do?

Few of my failed attempts :

```
grep -rnw ./* -e "^.*user_location.*public" *.php | grep -i "^.*SendQueue().*" --color
```

```
grep -rnw ./* -e "^.*user_location.*public" *.php | xargs -0 -i "^.*SendQueue().*" --color
```

Answer (score 1):

Print grep results with filename, extract filenames and pass those filenames to second grep.

```
grep -H ..... | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -d'\n' grep ....
```

Works as long as there are no `:` in filenames and usually there are none.

You could always do a plain old loop:

```
for i in *.php; do
    if grep -q .... "$i"; then
        grep .... "$i"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '
/SendQueue\(\)/ {             # hash all SendQueue() containing records
    a[++i]=$0
}
/.*user_location.*public/ {   # if condition met, flag up
    f=1
}
END {
    if(f)                     # if flag up
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)     # output all hashed records
            print a[j]
}' file
```

Testfile:

```
$_user_location   = 'public;
SendQueue()
```

In the lack of sample output you only get:

```
SendQueue()
```

For multiple files:

```
$ for f in *.php ; do awk ... $f ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `-l` option to your first grep, you'll get all the file names which you can feed to you second grep, like :

```
grep -i "^.*SendQueue().*" --color $(grep -l ...)
```

assuming you don't have special characters in file names.

Answer (score 0):

I can mention two ways of doing this:

**POSIX way**

You can use `find(1)` in order to do recursive search. `find` is defined by POSIX and is most likely included in your system.

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep -q "\$_user_location.*=.*'public" {} \; -exec grep 'SendQueue()' {} +
```

Here is the explanation for what this command does:

- `-type f` Look for files
- `-name '*.php` With the suffix `.php`
- `-exec grep -q ... {} \;` Run the first grep sequence individually.
- `-exec grep {} +` Run the second grep sequence on the files that were matched previously.

**Ripgrep way**

[ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) is a really fast recursive `grep` tool. This will take much less search time, but you will need to obtain it separately.

```sh
rg --glob '*.php' -l "\$_user_location.*=.*'public" | xargs rg 'SendQueue\(\)'
```

Here is the explanation for what this command does:

- `--glob '*.php'` Only looks inside files with the suffix `.php`
- `-l` Only lists files that match
- We enter the first query and pipe all the matching files to `xargs`
- `xargs` runs `rg` with the second query and adds the received files as arguments so that `ripgrep` only searches those files.

**Which one to use**

`ripgrep` really shines on huge directories, but it really isn't necessary otherwise for what you are asking. Picking `find` is enough for most cases. The time you will spend obtaining `ripgrep` will probably be more than the time you will save by using it for this specific operation. `ripgrep` is a really nice tool regardless.

**EDIT:**

The `find` command has 2 `-exec` options:

- `-exec grep (...) {} \;` This calls the grep command for each file match. This will run the following:

```sh
grep (query) file1.php
grep (query) file2.php
grep (query) file3.php
```

`find` tracks the command result for each file, and passes them to the next test if they succeed.

- `-exec grep (...) {} +` This calls the command with all the files attached as arguments. This will expand as:

```sh
grep (query) file1.php file2.php file3.php
```

Comment: Can you explain this format :  find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep -q "String1" {} \; -exec grep 'String2' {} + . The {} \: amd {} + parts

Comment: @rajsdev I have added explanations to the end, hope they are helpful

Answer (score 0):

### Some alternative, could be quicker...

#### 1. Using `sed`

```
sed -s '/\(SendQueue()\|_user_location   = \o47public\)/H;${ x;s/\n/  /g;/SendQueue.*_user_location\|_user_location.*SendQueue/F;};d' *.php
```

Could by write:

```
sed -s '
    /\(SendQueue()\|_user_location   = \o47public\)/H;
    ${
        x;
        s/\n/  /g;
        /SendQueue.*_user_location\|_user_location.*SendQueue/F;
    };
    d' *.php
```

Or with `find`:

```
find /path -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -s '
    /\(SendQueue()\|_user_location   = \o47public\)/H;
    ${
        x;
        s/\n/  /g;
        /SendQueue.*_user_location\|_user_location.*SendQueue/F;
    };
    d' {} +
```

#### 2. Using `grep`

But reading each file only 1 time

```
grep -c "\(SendQueue()\|_user_location   = 'public\)" *.php | grep :2$
```

or

```
grep -c "\(SendQueue()\|_user_location   = 'public\)" *.txt | sed -ne 's/:2$//p'
```

Then

```
find /path -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep -c \
    "\(SendQueue()\|_user_location   = 'public\)" {} + |
    sed -ne 's/:2$//p'
```

Of course, this work only if you're sure all sentence could be present only once.

### Remark

To ensure no commented line will polute result, you could replace regex by

```
"^[^#/]*\(SendQueue()\|_user_location   = 'public\)"
```

In all submited alternatives